# React - where to place constants used in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conventions

I have a value I need to use in the render method of a class. The value is derived from some a function that takes a while to run, but won't change after it's assigned. The render function will be called repeatedly and I don't want to recalculate the value each time it's called. So where is the appropriate place to assign the value? I could access it as state like so:

```
    export default React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return {
                value: this.expensiveFunction()
        },

        expensiveFunction: function() {
            //function that takes a while to run
        }

        render: function() {
            return({value});
        }
    });
```

But since "value" above won't ever change, that doesn't seem right.

Comment: You should do the `expensiveFunction` in the parent and then pass value as a prop. Your render method should not be calling the `expensiveFunction`

Comment: Getinitialstate is called once. Just access your state from anywhere after.

Comment: Right, right. It should, as Chase suggests, just be passed as a prop from the parent. Not sure what I was thinking.